# Can I create a framework with SPM and add dependency with cocoaPods?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

In the current project it uses SPM and we have a service that is only available for cocoaPods. So I decided to create a module in SPM to consume a lib in CocoaPods. However I am not succeeding in doing this. Can you tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to achieve what you want.
The first is to build and package the library that is available for CocoaPods  as a binary xcframework, commit this to your repo and add a local SwiftPM package with binary dependency:

```
 targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "SomeLibOnDisk",
            path: "localFolder/SomeLibOnDisk.zip"
        )
    ]
```

Then on your project declare a dependency on that package.

The second is to simply add the source files of that library in your repository and then add in a local SwiftPM manifest a target to build it. This will only work if the library is pure Swift. Also you could add the library as a submodule instead of copying the source files so that you can pull updates easier. This is tricky because you might need to also configure/copy any custom build settings and rules.